# How to hide the title bar of mainwindow without hiding the minimize, resize and close button in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface

I am creating an app in Qt that requires to have a title bar like the one in itunes 11. It should

1. Hide the borders
2. Have a customized title bar with contents(like the title bar of itunes 11 where the player control buttons are packed inside the title bar).
3. Retain the drag around default property of the title bar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> 1 Hide the borders

See `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and the other window flags

> 2 Have a customized title bar with contents(like the title bar of itunes 11 where the player control buttons are packed inside the title bar).

You need to draw one yourself. For instance you could make a custom widget and place it on the top or similar.

> 3 Retain the drag around default property of the title bar.

And you need to implement this yourself as well. This is actually quite easy -- just make your custom widget react to mouse events. Rough plan:

1. in the `mousePressEvent` handler accept the event remember the position of the mouse press
2. you will then get mouse move events (as you accepted the press), so override `mouseMoveEvent` and move the window (`move`, `setPos`) by the 2D vector (... QPoint) `currentPos - savedPos`

Comment: That really worked. Thanks a lot! But is there a way I can do all that without hiding the minimize, resize, close button?

Comment: What do you mean? Once you remove the frame around your window, they're of course gone. Do you want to replicate them inside your custom titlebar?

Comment: Exactly. I want to replicate them inside the custom titlebar. Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: The icons themselves are exposed through `QStyle::standardIcon`. You could probably use `QToolButton`s with a fixed size for them? Also, check out `QMdiSubWindow` source and see how it draws its fake title bar, maybe you can get some good hints.